Apply A Function With Parameters to a Dataset Query
If I create a simple Dataset like:
ds = Dataset[{<|"a" -> "the house"|>,<|"a" -> "the dog"|>, <|"a" -> "the
apple"|>} ]


NOTE: there is a new line character between "the" and "apple" in the last association assignment.
Per the WL documentation, applying a function to the Dataset to transform a column can be done as follows:
Query[All, {"a" -> DeleteStopwords}]@ds


And this works.
Now, if I wanted to apply a function that requires parameters I get a different result...at least to the extent that I understand how Query works:
Query[All, {"a"->StringDelete[#a, "\n" | "\r"]&}]@ds 


The last string containing the new line character has been modified, but it hasn't preserved the Dataset structure in the same way that DeleteStopwords did.
The intent is to remove the new line character, but preserve the Dataset structure.
Any hints on how I might do this?

Try this:
Query[All, {"a" -> (StringDelete[#, "\n" | "\r"] &)}]@ds

Because of precedence rules, you need the function to be in parentheses. The query already named the function, so using a named argument (#a) will break.

The named Slot is fine. It is only the operator precedence that is the problem.

@Edmund That's not what I'm experiencing in v14.1.

I have not downloaded v14.1 yet so that could explain the difference.  I'm running v14.0 right now.

Thanks.  Fixing the precedence solved the problem.  Also had to remove the named Slot  running on WPC version 13 kernel.

+1.  As indicated, the named slot cannot be used since this construction applies the function to each individual value, not the association as a whole.  Incidental to the question, but note that in this particular case, StringDelete has an operator form so we could just write {"a" -> StringDelete["\n" | "\r"]}.
